# Is the PTR for a mail server using DMARC, SPF, and DKIM only needed on the one main computer with the actual mail server?

Tags: email, dns, spf, dkim, dmarc

We have a website that runs on 6 computers in a cluster. So any one of the computers can be accessed using that domain name such as:

```
http://example.com/
```

On top of that, we have a 7th computer that is used for sending emails with postfix. That mail server is setup to send emails using DMARC, SPF, and DKIM.

At this time, our DNS returns 5 different IP addresses, using round robin, to any one of the first 5 front end computers, plus one to the mail server. If the mail server gets hit by an HTTP request, we forward it to the 6th front end server (i.e. proxying.)

So the DNS has entries like this (only with real public IPs):

```
example.com IN SOA ns1.example.com. webmaster.example.com. (
                ...
     )

                60 IN 10.0.0.1
                60 IN 10.0.0.2
                60 IN 10.0.0.3
                60 IN 10.0.0.4
                60 IN 10.0.0.5
                60 IN 10.0.0.7
```

As you can see, the last one is 10.0.0.7, for the mail server. The others are front end computers.

Now the question is: Do I need all the computers, 1 through 5 and 7 to all have the correct PTR so the mail server works as expected? (i.e. after all, a reverse look up will return all of those 6 IPs... but with the round robin, they will be presented in what looks like a random order.) Or do I need that PTR setup on the 10.0.0.7 computer only since that one is the one actually sending the emails?

My concern is that some mail server verifying our IP address may end up finding any of the 6 IPs that reference `example.com` and not just the one for the 7th computer (`10.0.0.7.` in my example) and as a result refuse the email because the reverse lookup failed.

I am actually hoping that only the computer with IP `10.0.0.7` needs the PTR. The others could have different names and no PTR.

Comment: From what I can tell, it seems that mail servers are smart enough to figure that out--they look up the connecting IP for the PTR, and the connecting IP will always be from the mailserver (10.0.0.7).

Answer (score 0):

If you look in the headers of the emails you send it had a "received:" which should list your LSIP (Last Sending IP) for that email. That's the IP address that's going to have the rDNS set up on it.  You can easily check that with [email testing tools](https://www.unlocktheinbox.com/mail-tester/).

But when setting up rDNS you really want it to be [fcRDNS](http://ipadmin.junkemailfilter.com/rdns.php) (Foward Confirmed RDNS)

It's just a DNS entry, just add the rDNS to all your outgoing IPs, which will alleviate your concern.